# aws code deploy: No such file or directory - appspec.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

When trying to deploy my rails app through code deploy I get the following error message:

```
No such file or directory - /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/b3ff73b4-aa93-4e49-99e4-c26cdcf7a6f0/d-06LE313R9/deployment-archive/appspec.yml
```

on a "BeforeInstall" error.

I have appspec.yml in my rails app root directory (e.g it is myapp/appspec.yml), and have no idea how to put the appspec file into the deployment-archive directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `appspec.yml` file should be at the root of the archive you upload to S3 or the GitHub repo you are deploying with. Try moving your appspec up one directory.

```
\
|-- appspec.yml
`-- myapp
    `--- (the rest of your rails app source tree)
```

Note that the appspec mostly uses paths relative to the archive root, so you might have to adjust them if you move your appspec.

Alternatively, you can create your bundle from inside your `myapp` directory so that the `appspec.yml` is still in the root directory of your archive.

Comment: I don't quite understand. How do you move the "appspec.yml" file up a directory? I zipped the "myapp" folder and uploaded that to s3 to be used on code deploy.

Comment: Never mind go it. Just zip both the appspec.yml and app folder into a single folder.